# Using "ec2-modify-snapshot-attribute" to automatically copy snapshots to another account

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, backup, amazon-rds

I want to use the ec2-modify-snapshot-attribute command to automatically copy **new** snapshots to another account.

What would be the best approach on this? A shell script run by a cron job?

Comment: What do you mean by "copy new snapshots to another account"? Do you mean *share* it with another account (which doesn't involve copying anything)?

Comment: Hello John, I mean sharing it with another account and copying it to another region on that account.

Account A takes snapshots, shares with account B, account B is in another region so it has to be copied.

Comment: Accounts span all regions, but each snapshot exists in only one region. Is your end goal for the snapshot to be accessible to a different account AND in a different region? If so, would it be acceptable for Account A to copy the snapshot to another region, and then share it from there to Account B?

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. I didn't keep in mind that all accounts span all regions. That would be acceptable, yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that you are wanting to do:

- Copy an EBS snapshot to a different region
- Make an EBS snapshot available to a different account

These actions can be invoked via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

**Copy an EBS snapshot to a different region**

Use the [`copy-snapshot` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/copy-snapshot.html) to copy the snapshot to a different region:

```
aws --region us-east-1 ec2 copy-snapshot --source-region us-west-2 --source-snapshot-id snap-1234abcd --description "This is my copied snapshot."
```

The snapshot will remain associated with the same AWS account.

**Make an EBS snapshot available to a different account**

Use the [`modify-snapshot-attribute` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-snapshot-attribute.html) to grant access from a different AWS account:

```
aws ec2 modify-snapshot-attribute --snapshot-id snap-1a2b3c4d --attribute createVolumePermission --operation-type add --user-ids 123456789012
```

**Copying NEW snapshots**

You also mentioned copying **new** snapshots. There is no pre-supplied logic for determining 'new' snapshots, so your script would have to determine which snapshot(s) you would like to copy. Snapshots copied to other regions receive a new snapshot-id, so it isn't easy to match the originals and copies.